# Create div scrollable elements according to the number of elements in an String array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm quiet new above all on Javascript technology. I want to create various div according to the number of string into an array of checked checkboxes but after my code it only displays one div every time... I must go through a jquery dialog to display it !

My JSP

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;" id="listCurrentContact"></div>
```

My listContact.js

```
varPopup = $('#dialogMultiplesDeleteConfirmation').dialog({
        resizable : false,
        modal : true,
        autoOpen : false,
        width : 500,
        open: function(){
            var SuppressCheckboxItems = [];
            // I put into an array the different value of checked checkboxes
            $("input:checkbox[id=suppressCheckbox]:checked").each(function() {
                SuppressCheckboxItems.push($(this).val());
            });
            var z = document.createElement('div');
            // I suppress the ',' between each element
            var test = SuppressCheckboxItems.toString();
            var tab = test.split(",");
            for(var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
                    z.innerHTML = tab[i];
                    $('#listCurrentContact').html(z);
            }
```

Comment: You might have to use append `$('#listCurrentContact').append(z)` take a look at docs https://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `.append` instead of `.html` while concatenating your checkboxes to `#listCurrentContact`.
You can refer this document: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp to see that .html() replaces the previous content with the new content whereas what you are trying to achieve here is appending the entire array of values to the div. Look at how `.append()` works in this link : https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-append/. Just to give you a brief overview, when you write a .append() on any element, it doesnot replace the previous content with the new content but instead attaches/concatenates the new content after the previous content.

Answer (score 1):

You should use  $('#listCurrentContact').append(z);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SaloniMishra Ive found the good answer. It just needed to change the .html() to .append() but with that if the customer just quit the jquery dialog and retry the previous elements stayed in the div so you need to clean every elements before to relaunch the function with the function removeChild()! Thanks all !

```
open : function() {
            var SuppressCheckboxItems = [];
            const currentDiv = document.getElementById('listCurrentContact');
            while (currentDiv.firstChild) {
                currentDiv.removeChild(currentDiv.lastChild);
            }
            $("input:checkbox[id=suppressCheckbox]:checked").each(function() {
                var z = document.createElement('div');
                z.innerHTML = $(this).attr("name");
                $("#listCurrentContact").append(z);
            });
```